# asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" the OnRowDeleting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Excuse me, 
I am following [this tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MySQL-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-GridView-using-MySQL-database-in-ASPNet.aspx)
On that tutorial, the command field using Link..
I want to use Button instead of LinkButton..
[image: draft]
I change my code to Like this:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"
                            HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
```

Behind code like this:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex != GridViewPaging.EditIndex)
            {
                (e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[2] as Button).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');";
            }
        }
```

then my OnRowDeleting method not working...

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int sales_so_id = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewPaging.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

            //delete operation
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteSO", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sales_so_id", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["@sales_so_id"].Value = sales_so_id;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Getdata();
        }
```

What should I do?
when I use LinkButton, everything is ok..
But, now the OnRowDeleting behind code is not working..
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use [this tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView---Delete-Row-with-Confirmation.aspx)

My previous onDataBound like this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex != GridViewPaging.EditIndex)
            {
                (e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[2] as Button).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');";
            }
```

and I change it into this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string item = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (button.CommandName == "Delete")
                {
                    button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + item + "?')){ return false; };";
                }
            }
        }
```

Now it is working..
Thank you